# Change SVG attribute (width, height, viewBox, and transform) to remove padding from the inner drawing

Tags: svg

I have an SVG (https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SBA2Xsi228agUO65FmtLwjg6Zuoq59-5) which is shifted. I have tried to change parameters such as width, height, viewBox, and transform attributes. I do not have a clear understanding of this area and it is not as simple as I estimated. I need to draw only the below part and remove the padding.

[image]

I do not want to use JS for this. Everything should be in the SVG file and I use it in the  tag. The SVG file should not hard code the width and height and should scale as per the  tag. It appears that the SVG file draws with left padding by default. I am trying to find the line in SVG that does it.

Comment: Use this viewBox instead of what you have: `viewBox="74 11 447 202"`

Comment: @enxaneta Yes, it works. How do you get the numbers?

Comment: I wrapped everything in a group `<g>`. In javascript you can get the bounding box of the group using the getBBox() method. This is returning the position (x and y) and the size (width and height) of the bounding box. You use those values to build the new `viewBox = x y width height`

Comment: @enxaneta I am getting the following 
`document.getElementById("g10").getBBox()
SVGRect {x: 74.21749877929688, y: 56.635597229003906, width: 446.4103088378906, height: 201.16091918945312}`. The y value is not 11 as you mentioned. But 11 actually works.

Comment: it's because the g10 has a transformation. If you want to use your values remove the transform

Comment: Removing the transform is inverting the drawing. It appears that one can get 11 by using the height attribute: height-bbBox-height-bbBox-y = 269-201.2-56.6=11. But then, I was trying to keep the width and height to default (100%) and use it in an img tag inside html.

Comment: Then do what I've told you: wrap everything in a group <g>